# Refresh on the same page in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am currently using React Router 6 and have trouble trying to refresh on the same page, specifically an authenticated and detail page (e.g. /main:id).
For example, my routes are configured as follow

```
const routes = ({ isLoggedIn }: RoutesProps) => [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: (
      <>
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      { index: true, element: !isLoggedIn ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/main" /> },
      {
        path: '/main',
        element: (
          <>
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <MainPage />
            </ProtectedRoute>
          </>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: '/main/:id',
        element: (
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <DetailPage />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
```

When I refresh my react app on url '/main',  my login redux state gets reset to false, which goes back to the Login component. Inside my Login component, a ueEffect hook is triggered to retreive the refresh token inside local storage, and if the token is valid it refreshes the token and sets my login redux state to true. This then allows me to go back to the '/main' page as expected. This is all good and as expected

However, when I refresh the page on '/main/:id', the page refreshes to '/main' not 'main:id'. I think I know why this happens - As I try to console.log the location using React Router's useLocation hook inside the Protected Route component, the location first prints 'main:id' but Protected Route redirects to the Login page as redux login state gets resetted. Then, the Login component updates the redux login state which navigates to main because of the routes set above. Finally, protected route gets triggered again, but this time the location inside protected route is 'main'.

Is there anyway to solve this problem? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that your `ProtectedRoute` component is using the initial `isLoggedIn` state from Redux to determine auth status ***before*** the `useEffect` has a chance to read from localStorage and update the redux state.

I don't know what your initial `isLoggedIn` reducer state looks like, but you'll want to make the initial value an "indeterminate" value, that is to say, a value that is neither true or false. `undefined` or `null` are good candidates.

From here the `ProtectedRoute` component will need to handle this third "indeterminant" state and not render either the `children` prop or the `Navigate` component redirect.

Here's an example `ProtectedRoute` component:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector(isLoggedInSelector);

  if (isLoggedIn === undefined) return "... LOADING ...";

  return isLoggedIn ? (
    children
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/" replace state={{ from: location }} />
  );
};
```

When a user is already authenticated and the `isLoggedIn` state resolves/updates to a truthy value, the route they are currently on will be accessible and returned and rendered.

When a user is unauthenticated the the `isLoggedIn` state resolves/updates to a non-undefined falsey value, the current location is sniffed and they are redirected to your login route. The location is passed so the user can be redirected back to the route they were originally attempting to access.

Here's a running codesandbox demo:

[image: Edit refresh-on-the-same-page-in-react]

You can also simplify your `routes` function a bit, if no `element` prop is specified an `Outlet` is rendered by default.

```
const routes = ({ isLoggedIn }) => [
  {
    path: "/",
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: !isLoggedIn ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/main" />
      },
      {
        path: "/main",
        element: (
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <MainPage />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        )
      },
      {
        path: "/main/:id",
        element: (
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <DetailPage />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        )
      }
    ]
  }
];
```